# Unit testing with dependency on HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, httpcontext

I need to test some static methods that rely on the current context.  Now, I can certainly use the `HttpContextWrapper` to remove this dependency from my own code.  The problem lies with the 3rd party API I am using in these methods.  THEY are relying on the `HttpContext` and so I can't do anything about that.  However, what I'm trying to do is set the `HttpContext` with my `HttpContextBase`.

So my code looks something like this:

```
public static bool IsSignedUpUser()
{
    //This calls IsSignedUpUser with the production context
    return IsSignedUpUser(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
}

public static bool IsSignedUpUser(HttpContextBase context)
{
    HttpCookie objCookie = SomeExternalAPIThatReliesOnHttpContextBeingSet();

    return (objCookie != null)
}
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
HttpContext.Current = context; //where context is a mocked HttpContextBase
```

This way when the 3rd party API is looking in the `HttpContext` for querystring, cookie values, etc, it doesn't throw a `NullReferenceException`.

**Why isn't this a dupe?**

In the code in the question referenced as a dupe, the author looks to be in complete control with no external dependencies.  I'm using third party libraries that have a dependency on `HttpContext`, I can't change their method signatures to accept `HttpContextBase` so I need a way to assign my `HttpContextBase` to `HttpContext`.

If this is not possible, and so far I am lead to believe that it isn't, then good answers should suggest how to remove these dependencies.  500 - Internal Server Error has at least one good suggestion.

Comment: Isn't `HttpContext.Current` settable?

Comment: You could also Mock the HttpContextBase class using libraries like Moq or RhinoMocks since it is in a unit test.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443746/mocking-httpcontext-session

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is settable.  Not sure how that solves my problem?  I am mocking the `HttpContextBase` and that works fine for my own methods that I can control.  In this case, an external API (which I cannot change) has a dependency on `HttpContext.Current`.  Made an update showing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @jessehouwing Don't think it's a dupe.  In that question the user has complete control over the API and the properties they need can actually be set.  In my case, while I can create an `HttpContext`, I'm unable to set everything that the API I'm calling is looking for.  I also can't directly assign my mocked instance of `HttpContextBase` to `HttpContext`.

Comment: @pete you're correct, missed that one.

Comment: Oh god. I wrote a library a while back that relied on HttpContext.Current extensively that makes me a bit scared you're talking about my Library, but I doubt it (btw, I've since repented for my ways and am in the process of reworking it to not do that)

Answer (score 4):

In my view, you should be replacing the call to SomeExternalAPIThatReliesOnHttpContextBeingSet with a custom interface method that you inject and which can then be mocked as any other.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] Per @jessehouwing, "Moles" is now "Fakes", which should improve your Google-fu

Ah, static dependencies...the worse kind.

It may be overkill, but I would look into perhaps using `Moles` (or whatever the heck they renamed it to), which will let you override **ANY** behavior, static, sealed or otherwise; here are some links to peruse:

- [Mocking the Unmockable](http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2010/04/28/mocking-the-unmockable-using-microsoft-moles-with-gallio.aspx)
- [The Moles Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798506.aspx)
- [Unit Testing with Moles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristol/archive/2010/03/07/unit-testing-with-microsoft-moles.aspx)
- [A different "Mocking the Unmockable"](http://www.slideshare.net/orbitone/moles-5655584)

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing - I knew they renamed it, just wasn't sure what they decided on. :P